# How to dynamically import all exported functions from a directory ? (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a file `main.ts` where I want to call imported functions:

```
import * as funcs from './functions';

funcs.func1();
funcs.func2();
// and so on...
```

Now in the same directory as `main.ts` I have a `functions` directory which does have a `index.ts` file where exports are declared:

```
export function1 from 'func1';
export function2 from 'func2';
// and so on...
```

These func named files are in the `functions` directory and all do have the functions declared as follows:

```
export function func1 (): void {
   console.log("Func1");
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to export the functions from the directory `functions` to `main.ts` somehow dynamically without declaring every function in the `index.ts` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes and no. You do specify each file you want to export all your functions from but you dont need to name each function. You can do the following;

```js
// functions/index.ts
export * from 'func1'
export * from 'func2'
export * from 'func3'
export * from 'func4'
export {onlyThisOneFunction, andThisVariable} from 'func5'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So yes for the function name specification and no for making those export specifications without `index.ts` (or in a file) ? There isn't a way to export them directly to `functions` scope for example from the `func1` file ?

Comment: @dossimusmaximus since typescript builds up a tree of dependencies and references between files (to prevent cyclic dependencies and to allow tree shaking), it does not offer such a functionality by default. Maybe there are some libraries that offer this functionality but I am not aware of one